# ERROR: Service [/spawn] is not available

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosservice, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following launch file:

```
<launch>

<node pkg="turtlesim" name="turtle" type="turtlesim_node"/>
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="spawnturtle1" args="call /spawn 2 2 -1 turtle2"/>   
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="spawnturtle2" args="call /spawn 4 4 0.5 turtle3"/>  
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="spawnturtle3" args="call /spawn 2 5 0.1 turtle4"/>  
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="spawnturtle4" args="call /spawn 5 2 1 turtle5"/> 
<node pkg="rosservice" type="rosservice" name="spawnturtle5" args="call /spawn 3 3 0.5 turtle6"/> 

</launch>
```

I am getting the error as given in title, sometimes it spawns 2 turtle, sometimes 3 with the error.

Can anyone explain this weired behavior?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287717/error:-service-%5B/spawn%5D-is-not-available./) by [sonu_patidar](https://answers.ros.org/users/34510/sonu_patidar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue comes from the service not being initialized/available when sending the request /spawn. In the output of the terminal you can see that the first processes always die and the 2 or 3 turtle spawned are the last ones.

You should (for debugging) add the attribute `output = "screen"` in each `node` tag to have more informations, you will see which turtles have been spawned and some erros like this :

```
rosservice: error: no such option: -1
ERROR: Service [/spawn] is not available.
ERROR: Service [/spawn] is not available.
```

You can directly understand the issue then. And to solve it, you should wait some time before spawning each turtle or wait for the service to be available before caling it.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0